# Create a label to a str series depending on what keyword is contained in the str

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a label to a str series depending on what keyword is contained in the str. I've been puzzling over this for a while and not sure how to approach it. Tried this:

```
mirantis['cat_label'] = np.where(pd.Series(mirantis.Mirantis_Address).str.contains('openstack|kubernetes'),'openstack', 'kubernetes')
```

It limits me to two keywords but essentially I need unlimited keywords. Any thoughts?

Example data:

```
https://www.mirantis.com/
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-increase-the-probability-of-a-vnf-working-with-your-cloud-qa/
https://www.mirantis.com/careers/
https://www.mirantis.com/company/press-center/in-the-media/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/mcp/sdn/
https://training.mirantis.com/openstack-courses-exams/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/transfer/
https://training.mirantis.com/kubernetes-docker-courses-exams/
https://www.mirantis.com/solutions/big-data-analytics/
https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-case-studies/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/transfer-services/
https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-videos/
https://www.mirantis.com/company/locations/
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/admit-it-vnf-certification-is-marketing-bs/
https://info.mirantis.com/mirantis-application-platform-beta
https://www.mirantis.com/support/enterprise-support-services/
https://www.mirantis.com/company/leadership/board-of-directors/
https://training.mirantis.com/certification/
https://www.mirantis.com/get-started/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/mcp/
https://docs.mirantis.com/
https://info.mirantis.com/live-demo
https://www.mirantis.com/solutions/network-functions-virtualization-nfv/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/build/
https://training.mirantis.com/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/ceph/
https://www.mirantis.com/solutions/container-technologies/
https://info.mirantis.com/eBook-MCP-Deployment-Guide_Landing-Page
https://www.mirantis.com/company/about/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/kubernetes/
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-deploy-spinnaker-on-kubernetes-a-quick-and-dirty-guide/
https://info.mirantis.com/webinar-vnf-validation-metaswitch
https://www.mirantis.com/company/press-center/info/
https://www.mirantis.com/company/investors/
https://www.mirantis.com/solutions/agile-enterprise/
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/introducing-mirantis-cloud-platform-mcp-spring-2018-release/
https://www.mirantis.com/partners/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/managed-services/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/operate/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/openstack/
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/
https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-brochures/
https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-events/
https://info.mirantis.com/contact-us
https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-webinars/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/application-platform/
https://info.mirantis.com/webinar-kubernetes-1-11
https://www.mirantis.com/blog/whats-new-in-kubernetes-1-11-the-qa/
https://www.mirantis.com/software/community/
https://www.mirantis.com/services/build-services/
```

Comment: add data sample and expected output in your question.

Comment: Please construct a [MCVE]. Sample input, sample output (currently and desired). Please also make sure that you include code to instantiate your sample dataframes, not just their string representation.

Comment: be free modify `mirantis = pd.DataFrame({'Mirantis_Address':['openstack ds','sd kubernetes f','clouds','sds']})`

Comment: I believe need `mirantis['cat_label'] = mirantis.Mirantis_Address.str.extract('(openstack|kubernetes|cloud)')`

Comment: How can a single condition have multiple outputs? For n different replacements you have to specify n-1 conditions. An example of sample input and output would be helpful to understand your need properly.

Comment: You said you're limited to two keywords but you show three in your code (which will not work).

Comment: @jezrael would this work if we don't know know whether a URL contains the keyword or not?

Comment: @NickDuddy - Not sure if understand - if not contains value it return `NaN`

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, I've poorly explained myself.  I'm trying to group URL's into content themes. I'm using keywords which may appear in the URL to try to determine those themes e.g. openstack, kubernetes etc.  I want to create a list of maybe 10 keywords and loop through each URL in the series and create a label for each URL if it contains a keyword in the list.

Comment: @NickDuddy - OK, so input data are list of this 10 keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
L = ['openstack','kubernetes','cloud']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
mirantis['cat_label'] = mirantis.Mirantis_Address.str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (mirantis.head(10))
                                    Mirantis_Address   cat_label
0                          https://www.mirantis.com/         NaN
1  https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-to-increase-...       cloud
2                  https://www.mirantis.com/careers/         NaN
3  https://www.mirantis.com/company/press-center/...         NaN
4         https://www.mirantis.com/software/mcp/sdn/         NaN
5  https://training.mirantis.com/openstack-course...   openstack
6        https://www.mirantis.com/services/transfer/         NaN
7  https://training.mirantis.com/kubernetes-docke...  kubernetes
8  https://www.mirantis.com/solutions/big-data-an...         NaN
9       https://www.mirantis.com/cloud-case-studies/       cloud
```